# How to recover multiple actions from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I send a url from one activity to another with different click actions? I tried to use `intention.putextra` but I can not resort like urls of the other buttons, it is not necessary to use two activities a second this with webview I ran with loadurl, but as I said I can only make a file, I do not know how to receive others In the same activity.

**Sending as follows:**

```
Home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(inicio.this,INSMainActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("hiphop", "https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCUnSTiCHiHgZA9NQUG6lZkQ");
                startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

**Receiving:**

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hiphop");
youtubeView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
youtubeView.loadUrl(url);
```

**As seen in the code I'm trying to load genres from the first activity.**

Comment: Did you mean.. pass different urls in different view onClick, but receive in same activity right?

Comment: Yes, I have different onclick events sending url to another activity that has a webview

Answer (score 0):

You are give separate on click and also separate view so don't worry about it. it will work

```
Home1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(inicio.this,INSMainActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("hiphop", "Weblink 1");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Home2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(inicio.this,INSMainActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("hiphop", "Weblink 2");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Reciving code

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hiphop");
    youtubeView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youtubeView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.

Comment: okay, accept my answer because others find out the solution easily.